# Driving into Belarus

Tags: europe, driving, automobiles, belarus, liechtenstein-citizens

I'm planning to drive into Belarus with my own car and have difficulties to figure out what I need to prepare. I made the following list, but  I also can't find a lot of information about the process, and I'm wondering if I missed something:

- car insurance: I need to check with my car insurance company whether they cover Belarus and if not, an extra insurance is needed.
- I need a visa to enter Belarus

Comment: In addition to having valid insurance for Belarus, you will presumably need documents to *show* that your car is insured, and also that it is registered.

Comment: You probably also need an international driver license to be able to drive there (I assume you come from another country).

Comment: From my own experience, you totally need the registration papers, car ownership, and tax papers with you the whole time.  It goes for driving a foreign private vehicle in Russia also.

Answer (score 4):

The following things are normally apply in non-EU European countries (except Kosovo and North-Cyprus).

**Car insurance:**

You need an European green card which indicates is valid in Belarus. You can get this from your insurance company. The BY-unit on the card must not be deleted, which indicates that you have a valid European Third-Party Insurance in Belarus.

You may also purchase extra insurance other than the mandatory third-party insurance. But this is not mandatory.

**Car Registration:**

You need the car registration form in common European format, which you should already have one.

**Car Number Plate:**

You need an oval FL label stick besides your number plate.

**Person:**

You need your passport with a valid visa.

You need a valid driving license in common European format. You'd better have an IDP International Driving Permit for general purpose.

You may need to buy extra travel health insurance. You'd better also take your European Health Insurance Card as you will drive through EU/EWR countries.

Comment: > "Ask your insurance institute, whether it is valid in Belarus or not. You may want to buy extra travel health insurance."

As far as I know EHIC is only valid within the EU. When you apply for Belarus visa on their embassy website they should mention whether you need a health insurance, I have sent an application for a visa and it got returned because I didn't include any information about the health insurance, so I then purchased one, included all the details (possibly also a copy of the insurance with the application letter) and then got a visa in 5 days.

Comment: @kiradotee I checked my EHIC, it is also valid besides EU/EWR in BIH, MK, SRB, TR and Tunisia. So I wander if it varies from issuing country or it's European standard. But you are right, mine is not valid in BY either.

Comment: What's the FL label?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to consider driving into Belarus is BelToll toll roads system - a pretty notorious set-up which might get you a heavy fine if you mess it up.

A

Comment: Adding more details would be helpful.

Comment: BelToll selling points can be found at the fuel stations. Directly you have the on-board device make sure you attach it right - every arch you miss loses you about 100EUR and you may score a few thousand euro of fines before you know it. They charge you first and then you can carry on / sue them if you think you were right.